# How to replace specific parts in string with javascript with values from object

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to make custom replacer method for my HTML output. But I can't figure it out. I guess it should be done with `String.match` and `replace` somehow.

I have some "error codes" in my string that always start with _err_ and I have a JS object with values.

What I want to achieve:

1. Find all string parts (error codes) that starts with _err_
2. Get correct key for my object - error code without _err_
3. Find value from Lang object
4. Replace error code with correct Lang value.

Some error codes may appear multiple times.

```
var content = "Looks like you have _err_no_email or _err_no_code provided";
var Lang = {
    'no_email' : "No email",
    'no_code' : "No code"
};
```

I can do it other way around. So I cycle the `Lang` object and replace those in string.
It would be something like this if using underscore:

```
function replaceMe() {
    _.each(Lang, function(value, key) {
        content = content.replace(new RegExp('_err_' + key,'g'), value);
    });
    console.log(content);
};
```

But if it can be done faster with my first idea then I want to know how.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nCgrX/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple regex should do the trick:

```
var content = content.replace(/\b_err_(.+?)\b/g, function(match, errorName) {
    return Lang[errorName] || match;
});
```

This assumes that you do not want strings like `"blah_err_blah"` to be replaced, and defaults to not replacing the text if the error cannot be found in your `Lang` object.

Comment: Instead of `[^\s]` it may be better to use `\w` so as not to include punctuation—and it's less to type. :-).

Comment: I think leaving it open (with `.*?` and `\b`) makes it a bit more portable, depending on what the author wants.

Comment: Callback function didn't come to my mind. I'll accept this answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var replace = function(str, object, regexp) { //if property not found string is not replaced
    return String(str).replace(regexp || (/\\?\{([^{}]+)\}/g), function(match, name) {
        return (object[name] != null) ? object[name] : match;
    });
}
```

This is a format function I've used in several projects thats quite efficient. Matches `{prop}` by default to {prop:'val'} but you can pass a regex for example maybe in your case `/_err_+\S/g` so it matches other tokens in your string.

So you can do:

```
var content ="Looks like you have {no_email} or {no_code} provided";
var Lang = {
    'no_email' : "No email",
    'no_code' : "No code"
}

var formatted = replace(content, lang);
```

Or for your original string stealing the other answers regex:

```
var formatted = replace(content, lang, /_err_([^\s]+)/g)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback function, that look if a key matching the error code exists in your `Lang` object, and if so returns the value of that (and otherwise just the key itself, thereby doing no replacement, like so:

```
content.replace(/_err_([a-z_]+)/gi, function(fullmatch, key) {
  return Lang[key] ? Lang[key] : fullmatch;
});
```

The first parameter passed to the function will be the full match, and the second parameter `key` will just be that part grouped by the bracktes.

And then, if `Lang` contains a (non-falsy) value for `key`, that’ll be returned, otherwise just the `fullmatch` value, so that that part of the string gets “replaced” with itself.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/VZVLt/1/

Answer (score 0):

One more variation with `split`

```
content = content
        .split('_err_')
        .map(function(str, index){
            if (index === 0) 
                return str;

            var whitespace = str.indexOf(' '),
                key = str.substring(0, whitespace)

            return Lang[key] + str.substring(whitespace);
        })
        .join('')
        ;
```